# How to install sqlsrv for xampp mac os version

Tags: php-extension, sqlsrv

I used XAMPP 7.1.11 for Mac OS. I could not find the extensions directory to install SQLSRV extension I try so many way to solved this problem about 2 Weeks. Is there anyone every setup PHP like this. Let discus together.